# almacenar en una lista de python los resultados de un input producidos durante un ciclo for

Tags: python

Dado el siguiente codigo que he intentado:

```
cantidad_mercaderia = int(input("introduce la cantidad de items en tu carrito: "))
for i in range(cantidad_mercaderia): 
codigo = int(input("introduce el codigo de tu producto: "))

productos = []
lista_productos = productos.append(codigo)

print(lista_productos)
```

Quisiera saber como puedo hacer para crear una lista que almacene los valores obtenidos de cada iteración del ciclo FOR.

En este caso la primera parte esta resuelta: Se le pide al usuario que ingrese cuantos productos necesita cotizar y el for se ejecuta esa misma cantidad de veces pidiendo el dato.

Lo que no logro resolver es la segunda parte: Como y donde se almacenan esos datos para poder manipularnos posteriormente.

Answer (score 0):

[append()](https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) es un método que no devuelve una nueva lista, si no que opera directo sobre la lista agregando un ítem al final.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a.append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = a.append(5)
>>> print(b)
None # <-- No devolvió nada
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Entonces solo tienes que seguir trabajando con la variable `productos`
Pero si quieres al final puedes crear una copia de la lista en otra variable:

```
>>> lista_productos = productos.copy()
>>> # o 
>>> lista_productos = productos[:]
```